# Can I avoid using stacked if statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm writing a program that has a cap on how many visitors etc. And if it reaches cap then it defaults and prints i.e. You have reached adult capacity.

I am looking for a way to shorten my code and not use stacked if statements (which I am using now. I am very new at this and I was hoping there was a way to do that by implementing the following?  However I'm not quite seeing how to get it to recognize and `System.out.print` specifics.

```
if (childCount >= CHILD_LIMIT || adultCount >= ADULT_LIMIT 
  || seniorCount >= SENIOR_LIMIT || totalPeople >= TOT_LIMIT || totalMoney >= GRAND_AMT)
```

Comment: If you post your existing code, it would be easier to suggest how to make your code 'better' (easier to maintain, possibly more succinct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to print different statements for different conditions, you should use separate `if` statements:

```
boolean error = false;
if(childCount >= CHILD_LIMIT) {
    System.out.println("You have reached child capacity");
    error = true;
}
if(adultCount >= ADULT_LIMIT) {
    System.out.println("You have reached adult capacity");
    error = true;
}
...
if(error) {
    /* error occurred, don't process input normally */
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had a feeling I couldn't condense.  Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: if 2 or 3 of the conditions meet cap they both have to print the reached capacity.  My if and or else if aren't letting it happen.

Comment: Then drop the `else` and use straight `if`, no `return`. If you need to track failure, use a `boolean failure = false` and set it to `true` in each failure. I adjusted the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain 3 `List`s.

One for knowing what you are comparing, second for holding the values, third for holding the upper limits.

Then you can iterate through the first list, using a `for` loop, and then inside it, you can put a `if` condition, comparing the values in the other two lists.

And put in a `break` in the `else` part to add in the effect of short-circuiting.